# AWS CloudFormation: Combining ImportValue and Sub functions causes error

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

When uploading my template to CloudFormation I am receiving the following validation error:

> Template validation error: Template error: the attribute in
> Fn::ImportValue must not depend on any resources, imported values, or
> Fn::GetAZs

I have a test template below that reproduces the issue:

```yaml
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-3bfab942
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: mykeypair
      UserData:
        "Fn::Base64":
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash
            yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
            /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource EC2Instance --configsets testset --region ${AWS::Region}
            yum -y update
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        configSets:
          testset:
            - "testConfiguration"
        testConfiguration:
          commands: 
            CreateTestFile:
              cwd: "~"
              command: 
                "Fn::ImportValue": 
                  !Sub | 
                    touch ${myexport}
```

To keep things as simple as I can I'm basically trying to create a bash command using the export. So in the above example I want to create a file named based on what the export value is. I don't understand the error message in the context of what I'm trying to do. I've validated that the export exists in another stack that I've created.

Comment: can you post the resource snippet that you are trying to import value into?

Comment: Hi, I've edited to include a template that has the same issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is not `Sub`, but you are not using `ImportValue` correctly. The thing you are actually importing in your code is not `myexport`, but `touch ${myexport}` as a whole. You should put your `ImportValue` inside `Sub`.

Also, if the export value is literally called `myexport`, you don't put it inside `${}`; you only do this if it is a parameter you defined in the template.

You could change that last few lines to this:

```yaml
command: !Sub
    - "touch ${filename}"
    - filename: !ImportValue myexport
```

Answer (score 14):

Just as a syntax alternative to the accepted answer, one might prefer to do:

```yaml
command: !Sub ['touch ${filename}', filename: !ImportValue myexport]
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks! Should have just tried it first i guess.

Answer (score 7):

I was looking to do the same thing but, with a different syntax as I had multi-line sub function content.
Below, is the code-snippet that worked for me.

```
UserData:
  Fn::Base64:
    !Sub
    - |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      echo ${VpcId}
    - VpcId: !ImportValue MyVPCId
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in JSON anyone needs:

```
PutItemToDynamo:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument: {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "dynamodb:PutItem",
            "Resource": {
              "Fn::Sub": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:table/${TABLE}",
                {
                  "TABLE": { "Fn::ImportValue": "QADynamoDBTable" }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed the importValue and !Sub combination into a string field. Finally i found the solution

```
Value: 
  Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${AWS::Region}-smth-${ParamStage}-VPC"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can with

```yaml
Command:
   Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "touch-${filename}"
```